# Showing $\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\log\prod_{i=1}^R \left[\frac{\alpha x_i^\alpha}{\sum_{j=1}^R x^\alpha_j+T^\alpha(n-R)}\right]=-\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

> I need to show that
> $$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\log\prod_{i=1}^R \left[\frac{\alpha x_i^\alpha}{\sum_{j=1}^R x^\alpha_j+T^\alpha(n-R)}\right]=-\infty$$ Here $x_i >0$ for all $i$, $T>0$, $n>R>0$.

Any lead on how to get the above would be useful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is just wrong. Take $T=1,n=2,R=1,x_1=1$ and we get:
$$
\log \prod_{i=1}^1 \left(\frac{\alpha x_i^\alpha}{\sum_{j=1}^R x_j^\alpha + T^\alpha (n-R)}\right) = \log \frac{\alpha \cdot 1}{1 + 1(2-1)} = \log \frac \alpha  2\to \infty
$$
for $\alpha \to \infty$

There are some further assumptions necessary. Especially as $x_i$ has different exponential behavior for $x_i > 1 $ than for $0 < x_i < 1 $. For the first one you have $x_i^\alpha \to \infty$ and for the latter one you get $x_i^\alpha \to 0$ for $\alpha \to \infty$